# How do you write classify that you are using a time varaible in R?

Tags: r, time

I am using R. I am including time as a co-variate in my model.

10:30, 11:56, 12:00 etc

Is there a way to tell R that my values are time measurements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a question for [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com) but I would recommend to use [**`strptime()`**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).

```
var <- strptime("10:30", "%H:%M")
```

You can return the value as time:

```
format(var, "%H:%M")
# [1] "10:30"
```

For further question just regarding `R` I would recommend [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com/).